# Ada record with constant access-to-object-of-parent-type

Tags: ada

I recently started learning Ada. I want to see if there's a possibility in creating a [`Boost::Statechart`-like](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/statechart/doc/tutorial.html#DefiningStatesAndEvents) framework in Ada. To do this I need a record structure with a constant access-to-object-of-parent-type component, like a tree node that statically points to another tree node, and **the parent pointer must not be changed at all times**. Something like this:

```
-- Not working sample

type Node_T is record
    Parent : constant access Node_T;
    -- error: constant components are not permitted
end record;
```

```
-- I wish to create objects of this type like this

Top_Node : Node_T (null);
Child1_Node : Node_T (Top_Node'Access);
Child2_Node : Node_T (Top_Node'Access);
```

It seems that constant member fields are not supported in Ada. So I resorted to using access discriminants:

```
-- Not working sample

type Node_T (Parent : access Node_T) is null record;
-- error: type declaration cannot refer to itself
```

However, using named-access-type as discriminant works

```
type Node_T;
type Ref_Node_T is access all Node_T;

type Node_T (Parent : Ref_Node_T) is null record;
```

However, from what I learned this causes the life-time of `Node_T` objects to be bound to that of a `Ref_Node_T` object, rather than another parent `Node_T` object. Is this true?

Are there any better ways of implementing what I need?

Comment: What is the purpose of your constant-access-to-object-of-parent-type component? In other words, why must it be declared to be constant?

Comment: Hi thank you for replying! The nodes are intended for describing a hierarchical state machine, where states are organized into a tree. Having a fixed tree structure makes the machine behaves more predicatively. I wonder if the compiler can make sure modifying parents never happens.

Comment: In Ada this is typically accomplished using information hiding and controlled access to data modifications. Are you familiar with creating and using Ada packages?

Comment: Yes. Hiding it in a package as a variable is not ideal. I want to use Ada's semantics to let the compiler know the parent pointer will not change, so that the compiler can choose, for example, to implement the parent pointer in the .text section rather than putting it in RAM.

Comment: How, then, will you rebalance your tree? Your question sounds like you are trying to approach an Ada program as though it were a C program. Ada does not actually have pointers. Ada has access types.  You are trying to perform early optimization rather than trusting the compiler. If you want a fixed relationship implement the tree in a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: The hierarchy tree is purely static and does not need to be balanced. I want to implement something like Boost::Statechart (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/libs/statechart/doc/tutorial.html#DefiningStatesAndEvents). Boost::Statechart describes the tree through templates and class inheritance, forming an inheritance tree.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234307/discussion-between-john-doe-and-jim-rogers).

Comment: If you want to create a tree, you should use a tree abstraction, such as `Ada.Containers.Multiway_Trees` or one of the other implementations of trees that are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternate approach to creating a finite state machine is described in https://www.sigada.org/ada_letters/june2000/sanden.pdf
This solution uses a combination of protected objects and tasks to implement the finite state machine.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate alternate solution for FSM is to use enumerations and arrays, and if you're going to need more than one, `generic`.

```ada
Generic
   Type State is (<>); -- Any discrete type.
   Type Event is (<>);
Package Finite_State_Machine_Domain is
   Type Domain is Array(State, Event) of State;
   
   Generic
     Start,
     Error : State;
   Package Finite_State_Machine is
      Type State_Machine is private;
      Function  Create    (State_Map : Domain)            return State_Machine;
      Function  Get_State (Object : in     State_Machine) return State;
      Procedure Send_Event(Object : in out State_Machine; Transition : in Event);
   Private
      Type State_Machine is record
         Current   : State  := Start;
         State_Map : Domain := (Others => Error);
      End record;
   End Finite_State_Machine;
End Finite_State_Machine_Domain;

Package Body Finite_State_Machine_Domain is
   Package Body Finite_State_Machine is

      Function  Create (State_Map : Domain) return State_Machine is
       ( State_Machine'(State_Map => State_Map, Others => <>) );

      Function  Get_State (Object : in     State_Machine) return State is
       ( Object.Current );

      Procedure Send_Event(Object : in out State_Machine; Transition : in Event) is
      Begin
         if Object.Current /= Error then
            Object.Current:= Object.State_Map(Object.Current, Transition);
         end if;
      End Send_Event;

   End Finite_State_Machine;
End Finite_State_Machine_Domain;
```